# Code is not working on an mac OSX with python 2.7.12

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, unsupportedoperation

I want to use this code for my data distribution, but I can't save the file or when I run this in python directly I got this error:

> Unsupported characters in input

I think this code is generated on a windows environment and this is not working for macOSX. I installed all necessary packages.

```
%matplotlib inline

import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import statsmodels as sm
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 12.0)
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

# Create models from data
def best_fit_distribution(data, bins=200, ax=None):
    """Model data by finding best fit distribution to data"""
    # Get histogram of original data
    y, x = np.histogram(data, bins=bins, normed=True)
    x = (x + np.roll(x, -1))[:-1] / 2.0

    # Distributions to check
    DISTRIBUTIONS = [        
        st.alpha,st.anglit,st.arcsine,st.beta,st.betaprime,st.bradford,st.burr,st.cauchy,st.chi,st.chi2,st.cosine,
        st.dgamma,st.dweibull,st.erlang,st.expon,st.exponnorm,st.exponweib,st.exponpow,st.f,st.fatiguelife,st.fisk,
        st.foldcauchy,st.foldnorm,st.frechet_r,st.frechet_l,st.genlogistic,st.genpareto,st.gennorm,st.genexpon,
        st.genextreme,st.gausshyper,st.gamma,st.gengamma,st.genhalflogistic,st.gilbrat,st.gompertz,st.gumbel_r,
        st.gumbel_l,st.halfcauchy,st.halflogistic,st.halfnorm,st.halfgennorm,st.hypsecant,st.invgamma,st.invgauss,
        st.invweibull,st.johnsonsb,st.johnsonsu,st.ksone,st.kstwobign,st.laplace,st.levy,st.levy_l,st.levy_stable,
        st.logistic,st.loggamma,st.loglaplace,st.lognorm,st.lomax,st.maxwell,st.mielke,st.nakagami,st.ncx2,st.ncf,
        st.nct,st.norm,st.pareto,st.pearson3,st.powerlaw,st.powerlognorm,st.powernorm,st.rdist,st.reciprocal,
        st.rayleigh,st.rice,st.recipinvgauss,st.semicircular,st.t,st.triang,st.truncexpon,st.truncnorm,st.tukeylambda,
        st.uniform,st.vonmises,st.vonmises_line,st.wald,st.weibull_min,st.weibull_max,st.wrapcauchy
    ]

    # Best holders
    best_distribution = st.norm
    best_params = (0.0, 1.0)
    best_sse = np.inf

    # Estimate distribution parameters from data
    for distribution in DISTRIBUTIONS:

        # Try to fit the distribution
        try:
            # Ignore warnings from data that can't be fit
            with warnings.catch_warnings():
                warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

                # fit dist to data
                params = distribution.fit(data)

                # Separate parts of parameters
                arg = params[:-2]
                loc = params[-2]
                scale = params[-1]

                # Calculate fitted PDF and error with fit in distribution
                pdf = distribution.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
                sse = np.sum(np.power(y - pdf, 2.0))

                # if axis pass in add to plot
                try:
                    if ax:
                        pd.Series(pdf, x).plot(ax=ax)
                    end
                except Exception:
                    pass

                # identify if this distribution is better
                if best_sse > sse > 0:
                    best_distribution = distribution
                    best_params = params
                    best_sse = sse

        except Exception:
            pass

    return (best_distribution.name, best_params)

def make_pdf(dist, params, size=10000):
    """Generate distributions's Propbability Distribution Function """

    # Separate parts of parameters
    arg = params[:-2]
    loc = params[-2]
    scale = params[-1]

    # Get sane start and end points of distribution
    start = dist.ppf(0.01, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale) if arg else dist.ppf(0.01, loc=loc, scale=scale)
    end = dist.ppf(0.99, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale) if arg else dist.ppf(0.99, loc=loc, scale=scale)

    # Build PDF and turn into pandas Series
    x = np.linspace(start, end, size)
    y = dist.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
    pdf = pd.Series(y, x)

    return pdf

# Load data from statsmodels datasets
data = pd.Series(sm.datasets.elnino.load_pandas().data.set_index('YEAR').values.ravel())

# Plot for comparison
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = data.plot(kind='hist', bins=50, normed=True, alpha=0.5, color=plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'][1])
# Save plot limits
dataYLim = ax.get_ylim()

# Find best fit distribution
best_fit_name, best_fir_paramms = best_fit_distribution(data, 200, ax)
best_dist = getattr(st, best_fit_name)

# Update plots
ax.set_ylim(dataYLim)
ax.set_title(u'El Niño sea temp.\n All Fitted Distributions')
ax.set_xlabel(u'Temp (°C)')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')

# Make PDF
pdf = make_pdf(best_dist, best_fir_paramms)

# Display
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = pdf.plot(lw=2, label='PDF', legend=True)
data.plot(kind='hist', bins=50, normed=True, alpha=0.5, label='Data', legend=True, ax=ax)

param_names = (best_dist.shapes + ', loc, scale').split(', ') if best_dist.shapes else ['loc', 'scale']
param_str = ', '.join(['{}={:0.2f}'.format(k,v) for k,v in zip(param_names, best_fir_paramms)])
dist_str = '{}({})'.format(best_fit_name, param_str)

ax.set_title(u'El Niño sea temp. with best fit distribution \n' + dist_str)
ax.set_xlabel(u'Temp. (°C)')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
```

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` -- This is meant to run in a Jupyter/Ipython notebook

Comment: I download ipython but i have know clue how to run it?

Comment: This code works fine for me verbatim. I don't think OSX is the problem. You need to [setup Jupyter](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Comment: I installed jupyter via pip (i have anaconda, too), but still is not running

Comment: And you started a jupyter notebook, pasted this code in a cell, then ran it? Note: You shouldn't run this directly from `python script.py`

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question! How can i run it in a cell? i open the saved XX.py document and i have only the options for downloding or saving?? Sorry for that stupidness

Comment: My laptop doesnt mark the file as a runnig file (green)! i didnt see any active terminal or notebooks.

Comment: Notebooks are saved in `XX.ipynb` files, not `XX.py` files. Try getting a simple active notebook running with like `print('running')` before running the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is only running under spyder or IPython!

Answer (score 0):

Your python interpreter is finding an invalid chapter because the encoding on the file is wrong. You need to change the encoding of the file to utf-8 you can do this by adding this line:

```
    # -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

To the header of the file that you are working on

You also need to remove the top line of the file:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Because it is for Ipython notebooks and you are using a python interpreter not a notebook

Comment: When i put this header in my code i got this error.

Comment: # -*- coding: utf8 -*-

Comment: There`s an error in your program: invalid sytax (Highligt the fist line with this sign %)

Comment: @123GuteLaune try running it with the %matplotlib inline